# Why do I get a Runtime Exception Accessing the size of an ArrayList from MEL?

Tags: java, arraylist, mule, anypoint-studio, munit

In Mulesoft I have an ArrayList stored as an outbound property with one element. It looks like this:
[image]

But if I try to access the size of this array I get an error and can't figure out why:
[image]

The error is

```
[Error: object is not an instance of declaring class]
[Near : {... message.outboundProperties.crm ....}]
             ^
[Line: 1, Column: 1]
```

And here's a flow that throws the same error:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<mule xmlns:dw="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw" xmlns:quartz="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz" xmlns="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core" xmlns:doc="http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/documentation"
    xmlns:spring="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" 
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-current.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/core/current/mule.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/ee/dw/current/dw.xsd
http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz http://www.mulesoft.org/schema/mule/quartz/current/mule-quartz.xsd">
    <quartz:connector name="Quartz" validateConnections="true" doc:name="Quartz"/>
    <flow name="tempFlow">
        <quartz:inbound-endpoint jobName="job1" repeatInterval="1" repeatCount="0" connector-ref="Quartz" name="runOnce" doc:name="Quartz">
            <quartz:event-generator-job>
                <quartz:payload>foo</quartz:payload>
            </quartz:event-generator-job>
        </quartz:inbound-endpoint>
        <message-properties-transformer doc:name="Message Properties">
            <add-message-property key="crmRequests" value="#[[]]"/>
        </message-properties-transformer>
        <dw:transform-message doc:name="Copy_of_buildUpdateRequest">
            <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    statecode: 0
}
]]></dw:set-payload>
        </dw:transform-message>
        <expression-component doc:name="Copy_of_Expression"><![CDATA[#[message.outboundProperties.crmRequests.add(payload)]]]></expression-component>
        <set-payload value="#[message.outboundProperties.crmRequests.size()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
        <logger level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
    </flow>
</mule>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrap the expression inside bracket:

```
<set-payload value="#[(message.outboundProperties.crmRequests).size()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

For further testing you can try other *java.util.ArrayList* methods, e.g.: `(message.outboundProperties.crmRequests).get(0)`

Comment: Awesome, this worked! Any idea why it has to be in brackets?

Comment: Just from my observations, mules seems to sometimes have difficulty with chaining.  Using intermediate values or brackets seems to eliminate it.

Answer (score 2):

If you have set the ArrayList to be stored in crmRequests. Why in the debug  view it is showing the entire #[[message.outboundProperties.crmRequest] seems something wrong. It should appears in outboundProperties tab with single name crmRequests with the type of ArrayList. Check that out.

Also try setting with `#[message.outboundProperties.'crmRequests'.size()]` or `#[message.outboundProperties.['crmRequests'].size()]`.

Edit: Sample Flow, have done a small change set the outboundProperties inside groovy itself instead of using MessageProperties and then with expression component.

```
<flow name="checkFlow">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <dw:transform-message doc:name="Transform Message">
        <dw:set-payload><![CDATA[%dw 1.0
 %output application/java
 ---
{
 statusCode:0
}]]></dw:set-payload>
    </dw:transform-message>
    <scripting:component doc:name="Groovy">
        <scripting:script engine="Groovy"><!  [CDATA[message.setOutboundProperty('crmRequests',payload);
return payload;]]></scripting:script>
    </scripting:component>
     <set-payload value="#[message.outboundProperties.crmRequests.size()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>

    <logger  level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</flow>
```

Comment: This is the MEL expression evaluator, the debug view looks different. No luck on those expressions you posted, they give the same error

Comment: Show up your flow Please

Comment: Don't know if it'll help but I posted one

Comment: I did edited the flow, made the outboundProperties to set  inside groovy and able to do with your expression.

Answer (score 2):

```
#[message.outboundProperties.crmRequests.size()]
```

Mule was unable to resolve above MEL. Follow this two step approach for desired results. Use:

```
<set-variable variableName="crmRequestsList" value="#[message.outboundProperties.crmRequests]" doc:name="Variable" />
<set-payload value="#[flowVars.crmRequestsList.size()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Instead of:

```
<set-payload value="#[message.outboundProperties.crmRequests.size()]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set a variable and assign value to it and call it in your payload you can check it there.